# Are "review and guide me" on topic?

Tags: support, scope, broken-code

I am writing a pooled memory management. It works to some degree. You can allocate and deallocate
but it is missing some crucial parts like avoiding/reducing fragmentation and safety checks.
I basically want to be guided on how to go further (and also how to improve the code itself).
Neither Stack Overflow or Software Engineering seem to be suited for this kind of "question". I wondered whether I can post it here instead?

Comment: It would be on-topic to post what you have that works and request feedback on *that* part - you can even specify that you haven't solved the problems of fragmentation and safety checks yet, *provided that you are not also asking how to go about implementing these features*, since we review code that's implemented and working as intended - I would think Software Engineering a good place to ask how to go about tackling those problems, at a high-abstraction level at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To the best of my knowledge, does the code work as intended?
>
> Code Review aims to help improve working code. **If you are trying to figure out why your program crashes or produces a wrong result, ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) instead.** Code Review is also not the place to ask for implementing new features.
>
> – https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

From this we can extract the part of your question that may be on or off topic:

> it is missing some crucial parts like avoiding/reducing fragmentation and safety checks.
> I basically want to be guided on how to go further

It entirely depends on on what you mean by "further":

- 'How can I avoiding/reducing fragmentation and safety checks'
  This would be off-topic as your code does not work as intended. And you are asking us to change it.
- 'How to improve the code itself'
  This would be on-topic as you code would be working as you intend and you *just* want a code review.

However given that you've said the second is not what you mean by "further" I think your question would be off-topic.